# Can't implement Parcelable if properties of object are non-parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable

Let's say I have the following class structure

```
public class SipService implements Parcelable{

public SipCore sipcore;
public PhoneRinger phoneringer;
public CurrentML currentml;
public AManager amanager;
//etc...
}
```

All the properties of SipService are non-parcelable classes.  And the properties of those properties are non-parcelable classes.  And the properties of those properties of those properties are non-parcelable classes.  And the properties of those properties etc.... are non-parcelable classes.

I do not have access the to the source code for any of those classes of the properties of SipService.

Does this mean that SipService can not successfully implement Parcelable?

Comment: Do you have access to all vars of these classes?

Comment: I do not have access to the vars of all those classes.  Those classes belong to a library of other objects managed by another team.  And they won't authorize me to make any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have access to all the member variables of the classes and can't change this, you can't make SipService parcelable.

If you would have access, you could read all the variables of the classes in your SipService and make a new instance of them. But for that you need the getters and a appropriate constructor for each class to rebuild them.

If these classes are implementing the Serializable interface, you could make it serializable. Because it's behaving pretty much the same, but the performance is better if the class implements parcelable.

OR

If you can talk to the team, suggest them to implement the parcelable/serializable interface if it's a reasonable requirement.

Comment: Would serializability have the similar requirement as parcelability?  Ie. all properties of an object must also have implemented serializable?

Comment: Yes it would be the same

Comment: ok thanks Steve, so then this is my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174294/android-passing-object-to-activity-when-object-is-not-serializable-or-parcelab